# Wordpress Installed plugin not displaying css and js

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ask if how to apply the css and js of the plugin that I have installed, for example I install the contact form 7 plugin and its css and js is not linking in my page. Is it automatically included or is there a code/function that I need to add.

Thanks!

Comment: it is automatically included by the plugin code, try looking into console for any network error, @SydneyLoteria

Comment: I checked it and unfortunately it is not automatically included :(